# auth_ldap.log is not appearing when auth_ldap.log = network in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, ldap

I've created a rabbitmq.conf and advanced.config for RabbitMQ intended to allow LDAP authentication with internal fallback. Because RabbitMQ is dumb and tries to use the installing user's appdata which is a terrible design for a Windows service, I've also redirected locations with environment variables:

- RABBITMQ_BASE = D:\RabbitMQData\
- RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE = D:\RabbitMQData\config\rabbitmq.conf
- RABBITMQ_ADVANCED_CONFIG_FILE = D:\RabbitMQData\config\advanced.config

The config locations appear to be working correctly as they are referenced in the startup information and cause no errors on startup.

**rabbitmq.conf** (trimmed to relevant portions)

```
auth_backends.1 = ldap
auth_backends.2 = internal
auth_ldap.servers.1 = domain.local
auth_ldap.use_ssl = true
auth_ldap.port = 636
auth_ldap.dn_lookup_bind = as_user
auth_ldap.log = network

log.dir = D:\\RabbitMQData\\log
log.file.level = info
log.file.rotation.date = $D0
log.file.rotation.size = 10485760
```

**advanced.config**

```
[
    {rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap, [
        {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"D:\\RabbitMQData\\SSL\\ca.pem"},
            {certfile,"D:\\RabbitMQData\\SSL\\server_certificate.pem"},
            {keyfile,"D:\\RabbitMQData\\SSL\\server_key.pem"},
            {verify, verify_peer},
            {fail_if_no_peer_cert, true}
        ]},
        {user_bind_pattern, ""},
        {user_dn_pattern, ""},
        {dn_lookup_attribute, "sAMAccountName"},
        {dn_lookup_base, "DC=domain,DC=local"},
        {group_lookup_base,"OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=local"},
        {vhost_access_query, {in_group, "cn=RabbitUsers,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=local"}},
        {tag_queries, [
            {administrator, {in_group, "CN=RabbitAdmins,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=local"}},
            {management, {in_group, "CN=RabbitAdmins,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=local"}}
        ]}
    ]}
].
```

I'm using `auth_ldap.log = network` so there should be an ldap_auth.log file in my log directory which would help me troubleshoot but it's not there. Why would this occur? I've not seen any documented settings for auth_ldap logging other than .log so I would assume it would be with the other logs.

I'm currently running into issues with LDAP, specifically the error `LDAP bind error: "xxxx" anonymous_auth`. As I'm using simple bind via `auth_ldap.dn_lookup_bind = as_user` I should not be getting anonymous authentication. Without the detailed log however, I can't get additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay looks I made two mistakes here:

1. Going back and re-reading, looks like I misinterpreted the documentation and believed `auth_ldap.log` was a separate file rather than just a setting. All the LDAP logging goes into the normal RabbitMQ log.
2. I had pulled Luke Bakken's config from https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/Dby1OWQKLs8/discussion but the following lines ended up as:

```
    {user_bind_pattern, ""},
    {user_dn_pattern, ""}
```

instead of

```
    {user_bind_pattern, "${username}"},
    {user_dn_pattern, "${ad_user}"},
```

I had used a Powershell script with a herestring to create the config file which erroneously interpreted those variables as empty strings. Fixing that let me log on with "domain\username".